# How can I apply position static once the bottom of the content is hit

Tags: javascript, css, position, tailwind-css, css-position

I am trying to make some code have the position static once the user hits the bottom of the content. The content is larger than the screen and currently I am using top-0 so only what is displayed on the screen shows, everything below it can be viewed once the user hits the bottom of the page.

I have tried bottom-0 but it does not seem to work, I was wondering if this can be done with css/tailwind without having to use JavaScript to check the height.

Note: I am using Tailwind.

```html
<div class="relative flex mx-auto ad-5-container">
  <div class="mt-8 lg:w-8/12">
    {{> components/ad-5/hero }}  
    {{> components/ad-5/content }}
    {{> components/ad-5/features }}
    {{> components/ad-5/testimonial-one }}
    {{> components/ad-5/conclusion }}
    {{> components/ad-5/testimonial-two }}
    {{> components/ad-5/footer}}
  </div>
  <div class="hidden pr-5 mt-4 lg:w-4/12 pl-9 lg:block">
    <div class="sticky top-0">
    {{> components/ad-5/testimonial-three }}
    {{> components/ad-5/ad }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```